# Systemctl: Java not found! when using systemctl

Tags: linux, centos7, systemctl

I am using **CentOs 7.5.1804** and have a problem with a service.
When i start my service with **systemctl** it fails with the message

```
which: no java in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
Java not found!
```

Following the error message i did a **which java**

and it returns

```
which: no java in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
Java not found!
```

But when i log in to the system as the user **app** i get a feedback from java 
java -version

```
java version "1.8.0_161" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

Here is a snip of my service located in /etc/systemd/system

```
[Service]
Type=forking
User=app
Group=app
ExecStart=/opt/div/ui/bin/service.sh -s start -t myserver
ExecStop=/opt/div/ui/bin/service.sh -s stop -t myserver
SuccessExitStatus=143
TimeoutStartSec=0
TimeoutStopSec=240
#install
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What do i miss? Any suggestions ?

Comment: what do you get, if you log in as user **app** and run a `which java`? I think if you run `java -version` with the same user, that has an error with `which java`, you won't get a correct version feedback

Comment: When i use which java i get the reply:/opt/jdk/current/bin/java
When i use java -version the reply is: java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode

Answer (score 2):

Systemd uses a fixed search path and strongly encourages using full paths for executables.

From the `systemd.exec` man page:

```
Systemd uses a fixed value of
       /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin.
```

Best solution is to use the full path to the java executable in your `service.sh` script.